# Plugging Monitor into Local Debian Headless Server

Tags: debian, monitoring

I have a debian server (headless) and I need to plug a screen into it for a few days to do some work on it. Thing is, when I plug the screen into the server, there is no video output. How do I get debian to start the video output via SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rebooting the adapter kicked in. Didn't really want to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Did you reboot the server after plugging in the Monitor?

Comment: no - hoping not to reboot the server

Comment: Some adapters will be turned off if there is nothing connected to it at startup and AFAIK there is no way to turn it on afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Often there is screen save software running. In this case, the screen should come to life once you hit a key on the keyboard. This requires plugging in a keyboard. Changing the screen saver options should work as well.

If you want X output on the screen, it may be better to use remote access like vnc-server or xrdp to get output on a remote screen.